# Multiple Runnable in a single thread -java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

I am trying to have a bunch of runnable threads that can be started one at a time. 
Something like

```
First(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //do something

    }
});
```

Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I think OP wants to serialize the runs of multiple threads.

Comment: am trying to have mutiple runnable methods. in a single thread.

Comment: That doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. Do you want a Thread that does different things each time it is started? Do you want to perform several steps in sequence? Do you want to perform several steps in parallel (multiple threads)?

Comment: i want to have several runnables in one thread. they will be doing diffenct things at diffenct times.

Comment: And how is it determined what runnable runs when? I provided an answer that runs multiple runnables sequentially. But now that I read your comment I'm starting to think you want to control the order of execution from elsewhere. If that's the case you should note that a method call always runs in the same thread it was invoked in. You would need to fill a queue in one thread and drain it from the other. If that's what you want I can give you an example.

Comment: No, OP wants that a thread to implement multiple runnable interfaces.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a single threaded Executor

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool();

service.submit(runnable1);
service.submit(runnable2);
service.submit(runnable3);
```

Answer (score 4):

> i want to have several runnables in one thread. they will be doing different things at different times.

This sounds like a bad design to me.  If your class is doing different things at different times then it should be split into different classes.

If you are talking about re-using the same background *thread* to do different things, then I would use a single threaded pool as in @Peter's answer:

```
private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool();
...
threadPool.submit(new First());
threadPool.submit(new Second());
threadPool.submit(new Third());
...
// when you are done submitting, always shutdown your pool
threadPool.shutdown();
```

The `First`, `Second`, and `Third` classes would implement `Runnable`.  They can take constructor arguments if they need to share some state.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just have multiple private methods:

```
public class FirstCaller {

   private void method1() { }
   private void method2() { }
   private void method3() { }

    public void someMethod() {
        First(new Thread() {
           public void run() {
                //do something
                method1();
                method2();
                method3();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

OR as pointed out by Ted Hopp

```
public class FirstCaller {
        public void someMethod() {
            new First(new Thread() {
               private void method1() { }
               private void method2() { }
               private void method3() { }

               public void run() {
                    //do something
                    method1();
                    method2();
                    method3();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start a few threads at the same time `CountDownLatch` is what you need. See an example here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/CountDownLatch.shtml.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to execute multiple runnables sequentially in a single Thread? One after the other?

```
public class MultiRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Runnable runnable1;
    private Runnable runnable2;


    public MultiRunnable(Runnable runnable1, Runnable runnable2) {
        this.runnable1 = runnable1;
        this.runnable2 = runnable2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runnable1.run();
        runnable2.run();
    }
}
```

You could then call `(new Thread(new MultiRunnable(... , ...))).start();`

This will execute the first Runnable first, and when that is finnished it will execute the second.

---

Or generalised to more Runnables:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiRunnable implements Runnable {

    private List<Runnable> runnables;

    public MultiRunnable(Runnable... runnables) {
        this.runnables = Arrays.asList(runnables);
    }
    public MultiRunnable(List<Runnable> runnables) {
        this.runnables = runnables;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(Runnable runnable : runnables)
            runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to define several `Thread` subclass instances and call the appropriate one depending on what you are trying to do.

However, if you really need a single `Thread` object that behaves differently in different circumstances, you can define a `Thread` subclass that has a state variable for controlling what it does.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public enum Action { A, B, C }
    private Action mAction;
    public void run() {
        if (mAction == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Action must be specified");
        }
        switch (mAction) {
        case A:
            methodA();
            break;
        case B:
            methodB();
            break;
        case C:
            methodC();
            break;
        }
    }
    public void setAction(Action action) {
        if (action == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Action cannot be null");
        }
        mAction = action;
    }
    private void methodA() { ... }
    private void methodB() { ... }
    private void methodC() { ... }
}
```

You could then create your thread and before calling `start()`, call `setAction`, passing one of the `Action` values.

As an alternative to a state variable, the `run()` method could examine external variables to determine the choice of action. Whether this makes sense (and whether it would be better) depends on your application.