# How memory consumption is less by implementing Runnable interface?

Tags: java, multithreading

In class implementing Runnable, to create Threads we are instantiating Thread class and calling stating methods by passing Runnable objects. Here to create two threads we are creating two Thread objects along with Runnable object. But in case class extending Thread class, we are only creating two objects for the class which extend Thread class.

```
class ImplementsRunnable implements Runnable {


 private int counter = 0;

 public void run() {
 counter++;
 System.out.println("ImplementsRunnable : Counter : " + counter);
 }
 }

 class ExtendsThread extends Thread {

 private int counter = 0;

 public void run() {
 counter++;
 System.out.println("ExtendsThread : Counter : " + counter);
 }
 }

 public class ThreadVsRunnable {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
 //Multiple threads share the same object.
 ImplementsRunnable rc = new ImplementsRunnable();
 Thread t1 = new Thread(rc);
 t1.start();
 Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
 Thread t2 = new Thread(rc);
 t2.start();
 Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
 Thread t3 = new Thread(rc);
 t3.start();

 //Creating new instance for every thread access.
 ExtendsThread tc1 = new ExtendsThread();
 tc1.start();
 Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
 ExtendsThread tc2 = new ExtendsThread();
 tc2.start();
 Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
 ExtendsThread tc3 = new ExtendsThread();
 tc3.start();
 }
 }
```

Comment: A few bytes in difference in memory consumption is totally irrelevant (you're not going to create millions or threads in any application), you should only concern yourself with what's right. (Which is to use a Runnable, since you should be using an Executor or ExecutorService implementation as a thread-pool, to re-use threads, and generally you shouldn't create threads yourself in a production application)

Comment: Why negative voting ? I have read this that why asking .

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Yes, `new Thread(r)` often is a bad thing to do in production code, but sometimes the right thing is `ourThreadFactory.newThread(r)` instead of `ourExecutorService.execute(r)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** instantiating a `Thread` object is more costly (resource wise) than instantiating a `Runnable` instance. The idea behind implementing `Runnable` over extending `Thread` is that of **thread reuse**.

Conceptually, a thread object can run (synchronously) any number of tasks (runanbles is this case). This is leveraged, for example, by executors.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {
     executor.execute(() -> System.out.println("test"));
}
```

In this case, a pool of 10 threads runs 1000 runanbles. The overhead associated with extending `Thread` increases the more tasks you have to handle (so although in your example the difference is minimal, if you would have to run 10000 tasks the difference will become noticeable).

Therefore, it is a good practice to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.

Comment: And clarify one thing here instantiating Thread means creating object for the Thread class directly or creating object for  class which is extending Thread class?

Comment: I meant an object extending `Thread`, as you did in your example. Although, considering `Thread` would be the superclass of the object that extends `Thread`, the `Thread` object itself will be instantiated as well when you would instantiate the subclass.

Comment: So you are saying creating object for the class which is extending Thread class is more costly then creating object directly to the Thread class right.

Comment: `ExtendsThread tc1 = new ExtendsThread();` is at least marginally more expensive than `Thread t = new Thread();`. Memory allocation wise, `ExtendsThread tc1 = new ExtendsThread();` might be slightly cheaper than `ImplementsRunnable rc = new ImplementsRunnable();Thread t1 = new Thread(rc);`, but considering that in the case of `ExtendsThread tc1 = new ExtendsThread();` you lose thread reuse it is almost certainly a bad trade-off.

Comment: Thanks..Could you please explain me how thread is reused in the Runnable case and not in ExtendsThread tc1 = new ExtendsThread() case;

Comment: Please see the first answer of this question for an example of a thread executing 3 runnables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555038/multiple-runnable-in-a-single-thread-java

Comment: In provided link,one Thread is doing three Runnable tasks one by one and returning that Thread back to pool.So whenever we are using Executors implementing Runnable is better because Executors would not take Thread objects as parameters right.

Comment: That is correct. A single thread is used to run the three runnables.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions patiently @alexrolea ,

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a `Thread` object you do more than construct that object. You also allocate a thread in the JVM, which typically uses an operating system API to do so. Operating system threads are cheaper than processes, but significantly more heavyweight than most other OS objects, since each thread has its own execution context that needs to be handled by the kernel. Additionally, each thread has its own execution stack, and space must be allocated for that. The actual memory allocation associated with a new thread is more than one megabyte(!) on most Java implementations. By contrast, your `Runnable` will only allocate a few bytes.

If you reuse the thread to do work throughout your application's lifetime then the memory cost is amortized. More significantly, there is a nonzero cost in CPU time to set up a new thread (it's usually a syscall which means at least one context switch, and sometimes the loss of the rest of your current thread quantum). Communicating new work to an already running thread can be much less work than creating a new one.

A good rule of thumb is to think of the concurrency related mechanisms exposed in `java.lang` (`Thread`, `Object.wait`) as low-level primitive operations, and the APIs exposed in `java.util.concurrent` (`Executor`, `Future`, etc.) as higher-level operations. The low-level mechanisms are (slightly) more flexible, but also harder to use correctly. The high-level mechanisms are equally powerful but usually allow you to think about your problem at a higher level of abstraction, which usually makes your program both clearer and more correct.

Comment: Here constructing Thread object means creating objecting for the class which is extending Thread class or directly to the Thread class?